# Kvm nested Virtualbox windows guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kvm

My setup is:

- L0: KVM, ubuntu
- L1: Windows 10
- L2: Virtualbox (ubuntu) or Bluestacks    (Android Emulator)

Symptoms:

- Bluestacks complains that Hyper-V is enabled and won't start, even though it is not in windows 'additional features'.
- Virtualbox will reboot the entire Windows guest once I run a new VM. I've tried changing basically every setting I could find.

I do have nested enabled:

```
$ systool -m kvm_intel -v | grep nested
    nested              = "Y"
$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y
```

Inside my config for my VM ('virsh edit ')

```
<features>
  <acpi/>
  <apic/>
  <vmport state='off'/>
</features>
<cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
  <model fallback='allow'>Haswell</model>
  <feature policy='require' name='vmx'/>
</cpu>
```

Any idea why I can't get nested virtualization working at L2 with a windows host?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: I assume I can't move a question. I've created a new one of there.  WHOEVER CAN PLEASE DELETE THIS QUESTION.